# How to recover a Win8 Storage Pool that had it's partitions deleted

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, storage-spaces

I have (or had) a 4TB storage pool that I had created using 2x 500GB drives with 2-way mirroring. Everything was working fine until I made a very dumb mistake. I was following some steps for something else and accidentally performed a [DISKPART CLEAN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465(v=WS.10).aspx) on the wrong drive so instead of wiping the partition information from my USB stick, I wiped it from my storage pool with all my documents (yikes!).

When I look at the storage pool Windows thinks it is happy and healthy except for saying that it is "Not formatted":

[image: [IMAGE: Storage Space](http://i.imgur.com/oC9I26C.png)]

However, the pool no longer shows up as a drive under "My Computer" and it shows as unallocated in the disk manager.

So my question is: Is there any way to reverse what I have done and get the storage pool back online? Or at a minimum recover the files and re-create the storage pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone finding this down the road I was able to resolve my problem but using partition recovery software. The specific software I used was [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). On-screen directions are pretty straight forward and once complete you will have to reboot but it worked.